# how to config plugin.xml to add android:name in application tag

Tags: android, cordova, plugin.xml

default config for android manifest is:

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I want to add android:name="com.baidu.frontia.FrontiaApplication" tag

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.baidu.frontia.FrontiaApplication">
```

how to wrote plugin.xml for cordova plugin?

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```
<feature name="FrontiaApplication">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.baidu.frontia.FrontiaApplication" />
    </feature>
```

Comment: it doesn't work , I want the result is <application android:name="com.baidu.frontia.FrontiaApplication">

Comment: config cordova plugin.xml ,to modify Android AndroidManifest.xml to  <application android:name="com.baidu.frontia.FrontiaApplication">

Comment: have you found the answer?